# Unpivot subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to transform this query result into rows instead of columns. Using Unpivot is possible, but I was not able to do this activity
see the code:

```
    SELECT
cast(IIF(DATEPART(HOUR, [DATA]) <= 4, DATEADD(DAY, -1, [DATA]), [DATA]) as date) as Data,
IIF(DATEPART(HOUR, [DATA]) <= 4, DATEADD(DAY, -1, [DATA]), [DATA]) AS DataHora,
SUM([FraturaContusao]) AS 'FraturaContusao',
SUM([Salpingite]) AS 'Salpingite'
FROM
(
    SELECT
        [DATA], ROMANEIO,
        IIF(( bAbaco.FRATURA_CONTUSAO - COALESCE(LAG(bAbaco.FRATURA_CONTUSAO) OVER (ORDER BY bAbaco.ID), 0)) > 0 , ( bAbaco.FRATURA_CONTUSAO - COALESCE(LAG(bAbaco.FRATURA_CONTUSAO) OVER ( ORDER BY bAbaco.ID), 0)), 0) AS 'FraturaContusao',
        IIF(( bAbaco.Salpingite - COALESCE(LAG(bAbaco.Salpingite) OVER (ORDER BY bAbaco.ID), 0)) > 0 , ( bAbaco.Salpingite - COALESCE(LAG(bAbaco.Salpingite) OVER ( ORDER BY bAbaco.ID), 0)), 0) AS 'Salpingite'
    FROM
    ContProdUIA.ABACO_DIGITAL_L2 bAbaco
    ) as x
WHERE
CONVERT(varchar, x.[DATA], 23) >= DATEADD(DAY, -16, GETDATE())
GROUP BY 
IIF(DATEPART(HOUR, [DATA]) <= 4, DATEADD(DAY, -1, [DATA]), [DATA])
```

this is the result of the query:

[image]

I need the columns 'FraturaContusao' and 'Salpingite' to be transformed with unpviot
something like:

```
Data| DataHora | Tipo| Qty
2020-06-23 | 2020-06-23 15:54 | FraturaContusao| 15
2020-06-23 | 2020-06-23 15:54 | Salpingite | 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest is to use a `CROSS APPLY`

**Example**

```
 Select A.Data
       ,A.DataHora
       ,B.Tipo
       ,B.Qty
 From  (
         -- your orignal query here --
       ) A
 Cross Apply ( values ('FraturaContusao',FraturaContusao)
                     ,('Salpingite'     ,Salpingite)
             ) B(Tipo,Qty)
```

Comment: it partially working, but only one column. :( you have an idea to work with two or n columns?

Comment: in your example, it shows an error with syntax. making some modifications has not yet solved the problem.
I got the following error:
'B' has more columns than were specified in the column list.

Comment: @AdelmoJunior was missing a comma, this was corrected.  Normally I test before testing, but you did not supply sample data as text.  I don't do data entry.

Comment: @AdelmoJunior Yes there methods of doing N column "dynamically" but you didn't supply your SQL Server version

Comment: @Johin Cappelletti now it's working. I am grateful for it.
I am studying sql, and apply with in my work (pbi).
Sorry for my bad english.